# How i can sort post with current user city in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, post

I am working on site where i want to sort the books (Custom post type) with user current city. For example if my city is Sialkot and there are three books with custom fields Sialkot show them on top. What i have already done is

1. Store user city as custom field
2. Get the current user city

Only need help for sorting data. Currently i am sorting with meta key and meta value.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your meta_key?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the below code and thats all

```
query_posts('&meta_key=popularity&orderby=meta_value');
```

Here popularity is the name of the custom field

Comment: I am already doing this but it sort according to db value... I-e first show sialkot then pune etc but i want when user visit from pune he can show pune books on top.

Comment: @MubashirNazeer ok for that you need to integrate ip to location so you can have the value of the city in the recent_city named custom field and then the same logic will work

Comment: @MubashirNazeer Please let me know how does the city change for current user frequently ? Is City change dynamically for current user or User needs to do manually?

Comment: @MubashirNazeer The city value will be return back from the api you will use for iptolocation.  And iptolocation get the users current city once user use the site his/her ip can give the location of the city

Comment: I am using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgeocode/ for getting the current user city

Comment: @MubashirNazeer please refer to the file named wpgeocode.php and find variable $user_city this is a runtime thing so whenever the page is loaded it will return you the users city and then you need it to save it  in custom field or you can directly sort your post by custom query and sorting the result by the collected user city

Comment: yes i get the city name at run time like this do_shortcode( '[wpgc_city]' ) can you guide me how i can add this value in query ?

Answer (score 0):

The better way to get sorted the current user city as below

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'books',
'meta_key' => 'user_city',  // SPECIFY YOUR CUSTOM FIELD SLUG
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order'=> 'DESC'
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Let us know if you still face any issue, Mentioned over comments :) 
We are ready to help you.

Comment: Thanks for you time please check my message on first answer. I already using this code. But i want some thing else...